# Nodejs restful API unable to POST

Tags: node.js, rest, express

I have created a REST API using nodejs which operates on redis, I am able to call the api using get method and it work fine but when I change it to post and try to call it using post. I am getting the error `Cannot POST`. I am attaching my code below, can you plz let me know what wrong I am doing

```
app.post('/foobar/:ticketid/:date/:from_time/:to_time/:seats', function(req, res) {
    var id = req.params.ticketid;
    var date = req.params.date;
    var seats = req.params.seats;
    var from_time = req.params.from_time;
    var to_time = req.params.to_time;
    var key = id + date;
    var result = {};

    client.exists(key, function(err, reply) {
        if (reply === 1) {
            //console.log("Key Found data from key: ");
            client.get(key, function(err, reply) {
                var output = JSON.parse(reply);
                var data = [];
                output.forEach(function(entry) {
                    var temp = {};
                    temp['from_time'] = entry["from_time"];
                    temp['to_time'] = entry["to_time"];
                    if ((entry["from_time"] == from_time) && (entry["to_time"] == to_time)) {

                        temp['vacancies'] = entry["vacancies"] - seats;
                    } else {
                        temp['vacancies'] = entry['vacancies'];
                    }
                    data = data.concat(temp);
                });
                client.set(key, JSON.stringify(data));


                result['response'] = 1;
                result['message'] = 'vacancies successfully updated!';
                res.json(result);
            });
        } else {
            result['response'] = 0;
            result['message'] = 'Invalid timeslot!';
            res.json(result);
        }
    });
});
```

I am calling using postman and also Rest easy plugin. 
In the url I am putting  `http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8081/foobar/`
and in the body I am putting the key value pairs

Code from Postman:

```
POST /foobar/ HTTP/1.1
Host: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8081
Authorization: Basic NDM5OlA5MS1RVDhQLUs4RzktTDU2
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: ab3cb383-62d4-475f-0e59-881a167156eb

------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="ticketid"

251
------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="date"

2016-05-14
------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="from_time"

18:00
------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="to_time"

21:00
------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="seats"

5
------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW--
```

Comment: How are you calling your post? BTW it's not correct way to pass params

Comment: @abdulbarik Have edited the question with the way I am calling it

Comment: you should not put the key/pair values in the body since you are trying to use url parameters. Either choose for a body or for the url parameters.

Comment: @RickRoy: Could you post the code generated by postman? (below the save button)

Comment: @DrakaSAN added

Answer (score 1):

If you are posting the values in the body, you do not need to list them in the URL.  Just make sure your header is set to `"Content-Type": "application/json"`

```
app.post('/foobar', function(req, res) {
    var id = req.body.ticketid;
    var date = req.body.date;
    var seats = req.body.seats;
    var from_time = req.body.from_time;
    var to_time = req.body.to_time;
    ....
}
```

Comment: now getting error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'ticketid' of undefined` I have set `Content-Type:application.json`

Comment: Can you show how the body of the post (from postman) is formed? Also, make sure it's `application/json` not `application.json`

Comment: here is the post body `{
"ticketid":"521",
 "date": "2016-05-14",
 "from_time": "18:00",
  "to_time": "21:00",
  "seats" : "5"
}`

Comment: It looks like everything is formatted correctly on both sides, without walking you through how to setup a post in postman, I'm not sure what is failing

Answer (score 0):

This is not correct way to pass parameters and get it

Try this way

```
app.post('/foobar/ticket/:ticketid/date/:date/from_time/:from_time/to_time/:to_time/seats/:seats
```

and post in this way from client side

```
/foobar/ticket/123/date/your date/from_time/your date/to_time/your time/seats/123234
```

And get it like this

check all params with `req.params`

```
var id = req.params.ticketid;
var date = req.params.date;
var seats = req.params.seats;
var from_time = req.params.from_time;
var to_time = req.params.to_time;
var key = id + date;
```

Comment: Or alternatively just use `/foobar` and request the data with `var data = req.body`

Comment: exactly, he can do